# How to access the session variable from multiple pages with PHP

Tags: php

I want to access `$_SESSION['roleid']` in *master.php*. *master.php* is included in every page. I'm only able to access `$_SESSION['roleid']` in *dashboard.php* after user login. How to access `$_SESSION['roleid']` in every page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login']==1) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;  
    $role_id1 = $_GET['role_id'];
    // store here in session
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $_SESSION['roleid'] = $role_id1;
    // $role_id=$_SESSION['roleid'];

    $a=$_SESSION['roleid'];
    // echo $a;die;
     if(isset($_SESSION["roleid"])){
    header("location:api/dashboard.php?role_id=$a?name=$name");
}
} else {
    header("location:index.php");
    echo "login unsuccessful.";
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you call `$_SESSION['roleid']` in the other pages?

Comment: I got $_SESSION['roleid'] in dashboard.php but not in master.php . @Carl Binalla

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['roleid'])){ $roleid = $_SESSION['roleid']; }`

Comment: Now I got  $_SESSION['roleid'] . But i'm unable to display records on the basis of role_id. I will check it again

Comment: That's because you sent that location header.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Where in that code can't you access the session? What happens instead?

Comment: When i tried  @session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION["roleid"])){  if $_SESSION["roleid"]=="2"){ displaying value }}. It doesn't work. @StackSlave How can i solve it?

Comment: I want to display the menus if $_SESSION['roleid'])==2 in master.php. Master.php is extended in every pages. @Nico Haase

Comment: @Prabina the given code does not provide anything about menus - please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work" and back that by reproducable code samples

Comment: I want to show like this, if roleid is 2.  <?php
 @session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION["roleid"])){

                          if ($_SESSION["roleid"]=="2"){
                           
                             echo  '<li>';
                                echo  '<a href="user_index.php">';
                                    echo  '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>';
                                    echo  '<span>User Profile  </span>';
                                echo  '</a>';
                            echo  '</li>';
                            echo  '<li>';

Comment: _"only able to access $_SESSION['roleid'] in dashboard.php after user login."_ ... You only set the Session value after the user logs in. And that makes perfect sense because the value relates to the user's role. Therefore it's also logical that the value isn't available when the user has not logged in. It's unclear why you want to be able to access it in that situation - it would just be empty anyway. You probably need to have another check in your master page to decide if someone is actually logged in or not, before you draw the menu

Comment: What could be done? I have no idea. I want to display menus on the basis of roleid after user login. @ADyson

Comment: Well, firstly you would have to put session_start() at the beginning of your master page so that, if there are session variables available, you can access them. Then you need to check whether $_SESSION['loggedIn'] is set, and whether it's true. If it's true, then you can get the role from the session as well, and display the role based menu. If it's not true, display something different as per your requirement.

Comment: When I did  @session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";die;
} else {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";die;
}, it shows me Please log in first to see this page. @ADyson

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: " it shows me Please log in first to see this page"...ok. And did you then log in? What happened after that? It's unclear what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: Yes , I did. @ADyson

Comment: Ok...so, then what happened after that? it's still unclear if you consider there to be a problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access the session variables you need to call `session_start();` on top of every page that will use the session variable. After the start call has been made you can use session variables like this `echo $_SESSION["my_var"];` and this to set the content `$_SESSION["my_var"] = "Var content";`, if you are unsure what the session actually belongs it is possible to check the content of the session by doing `var_dump($_SESSION);`. This will show all the data the session contains since it is passed as an array.

Please do remember that a session is not recursive through subdomains because of the cookie that is being used to track which session belongs to who. A session is also dependent on that headers are not sent yet since it needs to interact with the cookies.

To delay sending of headers do this:
1. Call `ob_start();` at the completely top of the scripts that needs to set multiple headers
2. Do the things you need to do like set headers and so on
3. Call `ob_end_flush();` to send the headers.

Here is the offical PHP docs on this: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php

Answer (score 0):

you should check `$_SESSION['roleid']`:
   * if having `$_SESSION['roleid']`, you will get it. On that code, you store `$_GET['role_id']` to `$_SESSION['roleid']` but `$_GET['role_id']` have no in all page, it's only in dashboard.
I think that. You should try.